# Sorting under admin grid is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, sorting

**Here is my code:**

```
class Dolphin_Slideshow_Block_Adminhtml_Slideshow_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('slideshowGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('slideshow_id');

        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
}
```

`getGridUrl()` function in **grid.php**:

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
```

`gridAction()` function in **controller**:

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('slideshow/adminhtml_slideshow_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

Updates:
Now, after so many try...i found if i removed foreach loop from preparecollection method then My Sorting is working....but after doing this....All store views title are not fetch into admin grid .. but there is no problem with english, french

Comment: check `slideshow_id` field is exits in  model  and second also check compilter is enable or not

Comment: Also try to change `ASC`   to `asc`

Comment: yes, slideshow_id exist in model, & i also replace ASC with asc but sorting is not working...what is compliter..?? u mean to say compilation tool under system menu...

Comment: are you using multistore ?

Comment: yes i am using multi store

Comment: Now, after so many try...i found if i removed foreach loop from preparecollection method then My Sorting is working....but after doing this....store views are not fetch into admin grid

Answer (score 1):

try this one may be it will help you for the filter and may resolve your sorting ...

```
protected function _filterStoreCondition($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I think You have to use this code and default sorting will work for magento `$this->setUseAjax(false);`

Comment: its not working